# Unable to connect Mac Mini to external display using USB-C extenstion cable

Tags: mac, display, usb

I have an external display (Dell U2720QM, 3480 x 2160) that is usually connected to my Macbook pro via a USB-C cable. Occasionally, I instead connect the display to my Mac Mini (M1, 2020, Ventura 13.0.1), moving the USB-C cable. It's hard to reach the USB-C port on the back of my Mac Mini though. So I bought a USB-C extension cable which, after connecting it to my Mac Mini, is easy to reach. However, when I connect my external display's USB-C cable to this USB-C extension cable, my Mac Mini fails to connect to the display. It's not seeing it.

Is this expected behavior? Is it not possible to connect a Mac Mini to an external display over USB-C when that USB-C connection consists of a USB-C cable + USB-C extension cable? Or does this suggest that there's something wrong with my USB-C extension cable? The extension cable works fine when I use it in combination with a USB-C cable to charge my MacBook, so the extension cable is not defective.

Comment: Are you certain the extension is data-capable, not just a charging cable?

Comment: I was not aware of this distinction. Is there a way to see this or to test? I guess my issue may already be the test …

Comment: I don't know a certain test, sorry. Hopefully someone else will. Wish you luck :)

Comment: What cable, what does it say on the packaging?

Comment: Packaging has left in a garbage truck. But pretty sure now @Tetsujin's first comment was right on and that I have a charging cable that doesn't do data.